# How to get array of numbers using ones() in numpy?

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

Hi I have a code in Matlab which is generating the following sequence.

```
[ones(1,6*2) 2 ones(1,6*2-1) 2 ones(1,6*2) 1]

ans =

  Columns 1 through 18
     1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    2    1    1    1    1    1

  Columns 19 through 36
     1    1    1    1    1    1    2    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1

  Columns 37 through 38
     1    1
```

I want to generate similar array of numbers in Python.

I have tried to generate as follows.

```
ConvStride = [np.ones((12,),dtype=int),2,np.ones((11,),dtype=int),2,np.ones((12,),dtype=int),1]

Ans= [1 1 1 1 1... 1],2,[1 1 1 ... 1],2,[1 1 1 1....1],1

ConvStride = [np.ones((12,),dtype=int),2,np.ones((11,),dtype=int),2,np.ones((12,),dtype=int),1]
```

required

[ 1 1 1 .....1 2 1 1 1 .....1 2 111....1 1]

Could you please let me know a work around here.

Comment: MATLAB is 'automatically' concatenating those 2d arrays (even scalars are 2d in MATLAB).  In `numpy` you have to explicitly concatenate the arrays, making sure sure that dimensions are compatible.  The answers tweak the dimensions of the scalars in various ways to achieve that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a list using a similar python syntax and then convert it to a numpy array

```
import numpy as np

x = [1]*(6*2) + [2] + [1]*(6*2-1) + [2] + [1]*(6*2) + [1]
ans = np.array(x)
```

If you want to do it all with numpy you can use `hstack`.

```
np.hstack([np.ones(6*2, int), 2, np.ones(6*2-1, int), 2, np.ones(6*2, int), 1])
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `np.r_`:

```
np.r_[np.ones(12,int),2,np.ones(11,int),2,np.ones(12,int)]
# array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
#        1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

Comment: Wow.  I have never seen that piece of the numpy API

Comment: @James It's quite convenient. There's also `c_` and `s_`.